# Computer Unresponsive 30-45 Seconds After Starting Ubuntu 16.04 Mate

Tags: mate

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 Mate 32-bit on my old laptop, a Compaq Presario V5000, with 2GB RAM and 32-bit architecture. The OS boots up fine and I can log in. But, after 30-45 seconds the screen goes black for a second and when the screen returns my computer is totally unresponsive. The only thing I can do at that point is to hold down the power button until the computer powers down. The issue was repeatable, so I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and now I have no issues with my computer freezing.

I'm thinking there could be an incompatible video driver in Mate that is causing the issue. Can anyone tell me how I can check to see if I'm correct and how I can resolve this issue?